# Unable to connect to postgres database from django while running pytest

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker, django-rest-framework, pytest

Django project and postgres are in different docker containers.

I want to write the unit test cases for this application using pytest.

I have implemented test cases using `APIClient()` along with `@pytest.mark.django_db`. However while executing the pytest from local django application is not able to access the database as it is present in different container.

I have also tried creating a new image which includes the testcases, logged into that container and tried executing the pytests. However, it shows `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`

Advice how we can establish connection to host the postgres database from django in this case as pytest will not run inside the django container.

Note: Code coverage is also a criteria for us, so cannot use requests module to access the Django REST API's.

ever after using `@pytest.mark.django_db`:

````
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.2, pytest-6.1.1, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- c:\users\schitted\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
django: settings: app.settings (from ini)
metadata: {'Python': '3.8.2', 'Platform': 'Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0', 'Packages': {'pytest': '6.1.1', 'py': '1.9.0', 'pluggy': '0.13.1'}, 'Plugins': {'assert-utils': '0.2.1', 'common-subject': '1.0.4', 'cov': '2.10.1', 'djang
o': '4.1.0', 'drf': '1.1.0', 'fixture-order': '0.1.3', 'html': '2.1.1', 'lambda': '1.2.0', 'metadata': '1.10.0'}}
rootdir: C:\code\cc_cat_unittest_git\cat-eob-service\app, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: assert-utils-0.2.1, common-subject-1.0.4, cov-2.10.1, django-4.1.0, drf-1.1.0, fixture-order-0.1.3, html-2.1.1, lambda-1.2.0, metadata-1.10.0
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

test/test_django.py::test_unauthorized_request ERROR

============================================================================================================ ERRORS =============================================================================================================
__________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_unauthorized_request __________________________________________________________________________________________

request = <SubRequest '_django_db_marker' for <Function test_unauthorized_request>>

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def _django_db_marker(request):
        """Implement the django_db marker, internal to pytest-django.

        This will dynamically request the ``db``, ``transactional_db`` or
        ``django_db_reset_sequences`` fixtures as required by the django_db marker.
        """
        marker = request.node.get_closest_marker("django_db")
        if marker:
            transaction, reset_sequences = validate_django_db(marker)
            if reset_sequences:
                request.getfixturevalue("django_db_reset_sequences")
            elif transaction:
                request.getfixturevalue("transactional_db")
            else:
>               request.getfixturevalue("db")

c:\users\schitted\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytest_django\plugin.py:436:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
c:\users\schitted\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytest_django\fixtures.py:105: in django_db_setup
    db_cfg = setup_databases(
c:\users\schitted\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py:157: in setup_databases
    test_databases, mirrored_aliases = get_unique_databases_and_mirrors(aliases)
c:\users\schitted\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py:258: in get_unique_databases_and_mirrors
    default_sig = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS].creation.test_db_signature()
c:\users\schitted\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\creation.py:303: in test_db_signature
    self._get_test_db_name(),
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <django.db.backends.postgresql.creation.DatabaseCreation object at 0x0423ED60>

    def _get_test_db_name(self):
        """
        Internal implementation - return the name of the test DB that will be
        created. Only useful when called from create_test_db() and
        _create_test_db() and when no external munging is done with the 'NAME'
        settings.
        """
        if self.connection.settings_dict['TEST']['NAME']:
            return self.connection.settings_dict['TEST']['NAME']
>       return TEST_DATABASE_PREFIX + self.connection.settings_dict['NAME']
E       TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

c:\users\schitted\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\creation.py:161: TypeError
==================================================================================================== short test summary info ====================================================================================================
ERROR test/test_django.py::test_unauthorized_request - TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
======================================================================================================= 1 error in 19.76s =======================================================================================================```
````

Comment: This is not about the tests, but rather about connecting both containers. Read about docker networks and port publishing. Once you have that, update django's test settings with the correct db address.

Comment: I am able to connect both django, postgres containers and able to access the APIs. However when I am trying to execute the testcases from my local I am facing issue connecting to database.

Answer (score 0):

Check the postgres host given on the settings file. make sure it is connected to database container. usually, container name is given instead of IP on host

Comment: settings file already has the information required to connect to the database. I am able to run django server and access the APIs. but when I trigger testcases I am receiving the below error mentioned above.